# filterWithSelect in ember model Tables, remove regex

Tags: ember.js, filtering

Using [Ember Models Table](http://onechiporenko.github.io/ember-models-table/v.1/)

If I have set a field in my database to include:  male and female

and I have this in my columns:

```
    {
        "propertyName": "sex",
        "title": "Sex",
        "filterWithSelect": true,
        "sortFilterOptions": true
    },
```

This works great if I select 'female', but 'male' includes both sexes.  Is there any way to restrict it to the entire string, instead of it doing a substring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember-models-table's `defaultFilter` [does not do regex, only substring search](https://github.com/onechiporenko/ember-models-table/blob/01344934a1508938019800ceb971fb62f046a69b/addon/components/models-table.js#L56).

As per the documentation, you can supply your own `filterFunction` for each column taking the [cell value to check, the filter string and optionally the whole record as arguments](https://github.com/onechiporenko/ember-models-table/blob/01344934a1508938019800ceb971fb62f046a69b/addon/components/models-table.js#L946), e.g.

```
{
    "propertyName": "sex",
    "filterWithSelect": true,
    "filterFunction": (value, filterString) => value === filterString,
},
```